# SQL Server CE : multiple connections (2+ apps) to the same db (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

My C# WPF application using a SQL Server CE 4 database, everything works fine.

But when I want to run multiple instances of that app, I have problem: I can't open more than 1 connection at the same time.

As I understood SQL Server CE does allow multiple reads but only 1 write at a time.

I get an error

> there is a file sharing violation a different process might be using the file

What to do to fix it?

If some info is missing tell me about it in a comment

**Edit 1:**

Tried to add

> PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;

to the connection string but it causes error: Keyword not supported: 'pragma journal_mode'

**Edit 2:** As I understand Sql CE support more than 1 connection but only from the same PC, what I want to do is to connect to the db on network drive.
What can I do? (I can't use SQL Server Express etc. only single file db)

Comment: Are you using `SQLite` or `SQL Server CE 4` - those are two totally different embedded database systems......

Comment: @marc_s I use System.Data.SqlServerCe (SqlCeConnection etc.)

Comment: That's **SQL Server CE** (Compact Edition) - ***not*** SQLite ....

Comment: hmm, so this should support multiple connections even better right?

Comment: Programming makes me wanna cry...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, while ago. Since it is one time go, I used [sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to change pragma for database manually.

Comment: My db saved as .sdf file so it can't open it. also can't set PRAGMA no matter what I do...

Comment: sorry i replied this bcause you mentioned it's sqlite db. If you are using Why not try installing sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the free SQL Server Express if you need a database over a LAN